# stdbuf usage: increasing buffer size

Tags: unix, pipe

I've got an awk script sending out long strings (>10K chars) to stdout.

I would like to increase the buffer size so that larger chunks of those long strings are written at once. I've timed both pipes below with different -o sizes but there's no significant changes

```
time stdbuf -o 100MB awk -f processing.awk infile.txt | sort -k1,1 > outfile.txt
time stdbuf -o 100MB awk -f processing.awk infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

real/user/sys timings are all very similar to oneanother (+- 10% on each metric).

My question is whether I'm using stdbuf the right way? Thank you.

FZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) command manages to alter the buffering of standard I/O channels for the executed commands.  However, it doesn't (I don't think it can) alter the capacity of a pipe in the O/S.  So, I would not expect to see any difference in the performance.

Note that the difference is that with the big buffer, `awk` will end up sending all its data in a single monstrous `write()` system call (unless `infile.txt`, as modified by the script, is itself bigger than 100 MiB), whereas ordinarily it would write when a buffer of somewhere between 0.5 and 8 KiB is filled.  However, the benefit of such a huge `write()` is minimal; it still has to be segmented by the O/S to fit in the pipe (unless the O/S does things differently - classically, what I describe would be true).

Comment: Thank you. Do you see any benefit in staying out of the pipeline and diverting output explicitly within awk ( looping though stored strings and > outfile.txt within awk)?

Comment: If you need to sort the data, you'll benefit from keeping the buffer size smaller so that `sort` gets data to work on while `awk` is also generating the data, so you can take benefit from the parallelism of multiple cores in your CPU.  If you make `awk` hold off producing any output until it's done, there is no parallelism, and the overall process will be slower.  In the ordinary course of events, the default sizes for buffers are fine.  I would not expect to see more than second-order performance gains from tinkering with the buffer sizes.

Comment: THank you. Very instructive, useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

What `stdbuf` does is changing the buffering in C stdlib, that is, the buffer of `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` `FILE*`.

It doesn't change the size of the pipe buffer in the kernel. This is probably why you don't see any change.

It is a well-known issue that the pipe buffer size can't be changed and is quite small. When processing large files it is often better to write intermediate results into files rather than pipe them into another application. Because the pipe buffer is quite small there is going to be a lot of context switching between applications communicating through the pipe, the overhead of which may dwarf the applications run-time.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize the pipe buffer was set.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to buffer in a pipeline is to use the `dd` command. I have found a few cases where `stdbuf` does not work (eg: `git` on OSX) and it's useful to have the output drained before proceeding to the next step of the pipeline. Here is an example that will drain 1 MB before sending anything to `sort` while also writing 1MB chunks:

```
awk -f processing.awk infile.txt |
  dd bs=1000000 | # drain/write 1 MB chunks
  sort -k1,1 > outfile.txt
```

Another interesting use-case:

```
git ls-remote origin |
  # obviously psuedo-awk, might print out :refs/tags/{old_versions}
  awk '/filter for interesting stuff/ {massage output}' |
  dd bs=1000000 2> /dev/null | # drain 1 MB and suppress block summary
  xargs -n 10 git push origin
```